# iTunes says I have 8k photos but I only have 6k on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, itunes, photos, photos.app

I synced some photos from iPhoto to my iPhone. iTunes says that the photos were synced and there's 8000 photos in my phone.

[image: iTunes]

But when I checked my photo the photos I synced weren't there.

[image: Camera Roll]

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Photos you sync from iTunes don't go into your Camera Roll — they go into separate albums. Look further down the albums list to find synced photos.